# javascript node.js async-await electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, promise, async-await

I can't seem to find a relevant solution to this issue.

I am trying to use a foreach loop to call out for data. I have tried multiple variations of packaging this in promises but cannot seem to halt this function from proceeding before finishing the loop. Hoping someone may have some insight.

```
    async function getData(){
    temparray [] = { data to iterate over };

    await getAgents();
    console.log('done');

    function getAgents(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
            temparray.forEach((deal) => { 
                 pipedrive.Persons.get(deal.agent, function(err, person) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("trying to get agent " + deal.agent)
                    console.log(person.name);
                 });
            });
        }); // end of promise
    }; 
};
```

So what I'm trying to do here is create a promise that resolves once all of the async calls are completed, but the process marches on before this has completed. Hence 'done' logs to the console before the getAgents() function has completed and logged the names. I suspect it has to do with the callbacks, but I've tried converting it to a promise, I've tried util.promiseify, and I've looked at building an array of promises and then using promise.all but haven't tested it.

Comment: what are your async calls..

Comment: @NickParsons attempted, no dice. My understanding from the API documentation is that the function that calls await must be labeled async, not necessarily the functions called, as long as they return a promise.

Comment: Don't use forEach with promises. You could start with promisifying `pipedrive.Persons.get` (it isn't listed what is it and why it uses callbacks).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you should do with another example

```js
exec = async () => {
  let tmp =  [1,2,3,4,5,6];

    
  let value = await Promise.all(tmp.map(id => getIdAfterTimeout(id)));
  
  console.log(value);

}

  
getIdAfterTimeout = (id) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve(id);
    }, 2000);
  
  })

}
exec();
```

Comment: I'll give this structure a try in the morning.

Comment: use `.map` to convert an array of inputs into an array of `Promises`.

Comment: I did it as previous to illustrate the process and to understand easily. anyway changed the code

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function getData(){

  // this or you can do await 
  Promise.all(temparray.map(temp => getAgents(temp)))
  .then(data => {

    console.log('done');
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log('error' );

  })
  
  // if you do await .. do like this 
  
  const {error, data } = await Promise.all(promises);
  
  console.log(data);

}
function getAgents(id){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pipedrive.Persons.get(deal.agent, function(err, person){
                  if (err) 
                    return resolve({error: err, data: null});

                  return resolve({error : null, data: person});
      });
  }); // end of promise
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could covert a function with callback style to a promise.

My example for you case:

```
async function getData() {
    temparray[] = {data to iterate over};

    let persons = await getAgents(temparray);
    console.log(persons);
    console.log('done');
};

async function getAgents(temparray) {
    await Promise.all(
        temparray.map((deal) => {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                pipedrive.Persons.get(deal.agent, function(err, person) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("trying to get agent " + deal.agent)
                    console.log(person.name);
                    resolve(person);
                });
            })
        })
    );
};
```

You can use `Promise.all` or old school for loop (`fori`), I think you need read more about Promise async/await.

Answer (score -1):

I even was stuck in similar problem yesterday. I applied following logic to solve this

1. Create a counter that tracks how many async requests are completed
2. Increment the counter in the callback function of async request
3. Add check if counter is equal to length of array
4. Resolve the promise once the counter is equal to the length of input array

```
const fs = require('fs');

async function getData() {
  const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  // Create a counter that tracks how many async requests are completed
  let counter = 0; 

  await getAgents();
  console.log('done');

  async function getAgents() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      array.forEach((item, i) => {
        //do async stuff here
        fs.writeFile(`${i}.file.txt`, `line in file ${i}`, err => {
          if (err) throw err;

          // Increment the counter in the callback function of async request
          // Add check if counter is equal to length of array
          if (++counter == array.length) {
            // Resolve the promise once the counter is equal to the length of input array
            resolve(counter);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
}

getData();
```